# I just deleted all kext from System/Library/Extensions/ and my mac is stuck at boot screen

Tags: macos

I just deleted all kext from System/Library/Extensions/ and my mac is stuck at boot screen. Kernel was taking too much space so I thought lets see if I delete all kext files , I thought I deleted bootcache file too , is th is reason why its talking too long , mac is stuck on boot screen and its not opening

Comment: You need to restore from a backup

Comment: I’ve added another duplicate link which may be more helpful in this situation.